# Sort Points ad Clockwise C#

Tags: c#, math

I look some codes to sort my points by clockwise and all of them were like this :

```
  var lstPnts = new List<PointF>();
  lstPnts.Add(new PointF(23.92f, 6));
  lstPnts.Add(new PointF(23.88f, 0));
  lstPnts.Add(new PointF(0, 0));
  lstPnts.Add(new PointF(0, 6));

  List<PointF> a = lstPnts.OrderBy(p => Math.Atan2(p.Y, p.X)).ToList();
```

But result of them are wrong because this is the result that it gives me:

> 23.88,0
>
> 0,0
>
> 23.92,6
>
> 0,6

Where I have problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what is "sorting points clockwise"? What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: This is not a primitive or scalar collection but an custom object. You need to implement a custom sorting  algorithm (based on your requirement of how two items are compared or equatable to each other) while implementing IEquatable<T> , IComparable<T> . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The expected output is not completely clear. Some sample input and expected output, along with the definition of "sorted clockwise" would be helpful (what if the points are in a line?). I assume that the result is incorrect because the first two (or the last two) points should be swapped?

Comment: What are these values? Degrees? Radians? An angle and a distance?

Comment: @RonBeyer They appear to be points on a plane (based on [`PointF(single, single)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)), but it's a fair question.

Comment: I'm not a math expert but it's not an easy task to do. But first thing you need is to have a center point among those points. Then you can use Atan2 function to calculate the angle with the center point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var lstPnts = new List<PointF>();
            lstPnts.Add(new PointF(23.92f, 6));
            lstPnts.Add(new PointF(23.88f, 0));
            lstPnts.Add(new PointF(0, 0));
            lstPnts.Add(new PointF(0, 6));

            var avgPoint  = new PointF(lstPnts.Average(t=>t.X),lstPnts.Average(t=>t.Y));
            var ordered = lstPnts.OrderBy(t => Math.Atan2(avgPoint.Y - t.Y, avgPoint.X - t.X)).ToArray();
```

We found an average point. Then we calculated the angle between mid point and the other points and sorted our array with that angles. It may be in a reverse order. If it is so reversing the subtract operation will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem? You have successfully ordered them into counter-clockwise orientation

```
|4                      3
|
|
|
|
|2                      1
0,0----------------------
```

so just take the negative angle instead if you want to reverse the order.

```cs
var a = lstPnts.OrderBy(p => -Math.Atan2(p.Y, p.X));

foreach (var p in a)
    Console.WriteLine($"X:{p.X:0.0#} Y:{p.Y:0.0#} angle:{-Math.Atan2(p.Y, p.X):0.0#}");
```

> X:0.0 Y:6.0 angle:-1.57
>   X:23.92 Y:6.0 angle:-0.25
>   X:23.88 Y:0.0 angle:0.0
>   X:0.0 Y:0.0 angle:0.0

```
|1                      2
|
|
|
|
|4                      3
0,0----------------------
```

*Points 3 and 4 both have angle = 0 so their order could be swapped and still be correct. This is the same for points 1 and 2 in your original order.*